# Geting a float [0,1] uniform distribution from xorshift64* (uint64_t)

Tags: c++, random, x86

I´m implementing the Xorshift generators and others to compare their performances on my system - Windows and Linux.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift

http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/

I´m just now checking the generators with 64 bit states, like the xorshift64star from the wikipedia (here with my changes to trace the error)

```
double xorshift64star() {
uint64_t x = global_state[0];   /* The state must be seeded with a nonzero value. */
x ^= x >> 12; // a
x ^= x << 25; // b
x ^= x >> 27; // c
global_state[0] = x;
auto u64val =  x * 0x2545F4914F6CDD1D;
double dval = (double)u64val;
return dval;
```

}

However, running on an online compiler https://www.onlinegdb.com/ the double value returned is always 0 or **3.1148823182455562e-317**

I haven´t been able to find a solution on how to make the output from this function to be normalize into a [0,1] uniform distribution, without losing much precision and entropy.

What is the "corect" transformation I would have to do the output?

**SOLVED!**

Thank you @RetiredNinja.
The generator was already normalizing the uint64 value. However only casting it to double don´t seem to work for that particular compiler.

The solution was to use the custom cast from http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/

```
 static inline double to_double(uint64_t x) {
   const union { uint64_t i; double d; } u = {.i = UINT64_C(0x3FF) << 52 | x >> 12 };
   return u.d - 1.0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not really believing that an integer cast to `double` will equal a small number like `3e-317`

Comment: You'd need to divide by `(double)std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` to get a number between 0 and 1 from a uint64_t. Whether that is uniform of not is something you'll have to figure out. You might consider using something from `<random>` instead.

Comment: If you were looking here: http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/ you must have missed where the exact recommended formula is shown. `(x >> 11) * (1. / (UINT64_C(1) << 53))`

Comment: @RetiredNinja: It's entirely not uniform near zero. The reason is that the distribution of  possible `double` values is not even close to uniform, by design.

Comment: I was using the code from wikipedia @RetiredNinja

Comment: The answer you edited into your question is not an int->`double` conversion, that's type-punning the integer and using it as the bit-pattern for a `double`.  (And BTW, post answers as answers, not edits to the question)

Comment: @PeterCordes there is a pop up ballon if I try to answer my question, suggesting I could edit my question.  I assume that is what is expected.

Comment: That's there because some people post clarifications / additional questions in the answer box instead of using the edit button.  You actually *do* have an answer, and you *should* post it as an answer.  (You can search on meta.stackoverflow for more info about this if you want.)

Comment: The "SOLVED" code isn't even C++ !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your `u64val` is uniform between 0 and `numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max`, the obvious transform is `u64val/numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max`.

This is not the most accurate transform, though. The problem here is that you end up generating multiples of `1.0/numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max`. This obviously gives many small values a probability of zero. But consider this: the probabilities of all numbers between 0 and 1e-100 **combined** has to be 1e-100. That means you'd need to generate about 1e100 numbers to get *any* one of these numbers.

This basically means we've got an underspecified engineering problem here. Exactly how close should the approximation to uniform be?